# Category for homesteading, prepping, survival, off-grid, outdoorsmanship

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, category

For a website, wiki or blog forum, and as a category for organizing books—

Is there a category or meta-category that includes homesteading, prepping, survival skills, outdoorsmanship, and off-grid living?

This could either be a single word or a phrase.

Sample sentence: "I have organized my books by category. *[My word]* is my category for homesteading, prepping, survival skills, outdoorsmanship and off-grid living."

Comment: I suppose "kludge" might fit.

Comment: How about [*boy-scouthood?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22boy+scouthood%22). Or maybe [*frontiersmanship*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22frontiersmanship%22)

Comment: "Nature and outdoor activities" ?

Comment: I like frontiersmanship. The problem with outdoor activities is I usually associate that word with sports and recreation.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those refer to [self-sufficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-sufficiency).

Self-sufficiency (also called self-containment) is the state of not requiring any aid, support, or interaction, for survival; it is therefore a type of personal or collective autonomy.

Wikipedia

Comment: But in the US "independent living" means being in "senior housing" that is a hair short of a "nursing home".